# CAS: Password is not transmitted to LDAP

Tags: ldap, cas

I have an OpenLDAP server and I am very sure that the users itself are falid since I can log in with them with JXplorer. But when I go to CAS and I type in username and password, I just see the username in "Supplied credentials" and not the password too. This problem appeared when I changed my `deployerConfigContext.xml`with a "newer" one.

```
2016-09-15 11:45:33,747 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <LdapAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating anon>
2016-09-15 11:45:33,747 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: anon
WHAT: Supplied credentials: [anon]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Thu Sep 15 11:45:33 CEST 2016
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
=============================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just see the username in "Supplied credentials" and not the password too

You will never ever see the password.

Up your logs to DEBUG and that should tell you more.

Comment: OK, but before I saw something like [anon+password]. So I was slightly confused when it was suddenly missing.

Comment: Yes, that's taken away and removed. It was just a hardcoded "+password". Not an indication of "your password was received by CAS"